# Permission denied, please try again github

Tags: github, ssh, git-push

I'd like to have files automatically uploaded to my server when using the *git push* command. But the problem is that it stops at the keys and gives an error ( Load key "/home/runner/.ssh/key": invalid format ). On the hosting, the keys are added, in the settings of the github repository - too. Maybe someone faced similar? How can this problem be solved?

UPD: I fixed the error by changing the output of the key, but the following appeared .. [Writes access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBadh.png).

**Here is the updated code:**

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # Setup key
      - run: set -eu
      - run: mkdir "$HOME/.ssh"
      - run: echo "${{ secrets.key }}" > "$HOME/.ssh/key"
      - run: chmod 600 "$HOME/.ssh/key"
      # Deploy
      - run: rsync -e "ssh -p 1022 -i $HOME/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --archive --compress --delete . *server*:/*link*/public_html/
```

**Error code:**

```
Run rsync -e "ssh -p 1022 -i $HOME/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --archive --compress --delete . *server*:*link*/public_html/
Warning: Permanently added '*server*,[*IP*]:1022' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect from *IP* port 1022:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from *IP* port 1022
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change key file and folder .ssh permissions to

1. .ssh directory: 700 (drwx------)
2. public key (.pub file): 644 (-rw-r--r--)
3. private key (id_rsa): 600 (-rw-------)

lastly your home directory should not be writeable by the group or others (at most 755 (drwxr-xr-x))

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ssh1.html

Comment: And you are sure that the combination "echo "$" > "enters the key of the correct format into the file?

Comment: I fixed. But it didn`t help :(

Comment: What other way can be correctly deduced?